# How to get reference of child component in react-native?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, react-native

I had setup a `ViewPager` component in my `react-native` application which goes like this:

```
render(){
  return(
    <View>
       <ViewPager
         ref="main"
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderPage={this.renderView}
       />
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
           <Text>Something</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>     
    </View>  
  );
}

renderView(){
    return(
      <View ref="main1">
          <Text>Something else</Text>     
      </View>
    );
}

_onPressButton(){
    //Do something with {this.refs.main} and {this.refs.main1}
}
```

In the function `_onPressButton` I can access `ViewPager` component using `this.refs.main` but `this.refs.main1` returns `null`. But I want to get a reference of that View with the reference `main1`. How can I do that?

Comment: this.refs.main.main1 can you try

Comment: `this.refs.main.refs.main1` should work.

Comment: No, both `this.refs.main.main1` and `this.refs.main.refs.main1` are also giving `null`

Comment: try `renderPage={this.renderView.bind(this)}` and use `this.refs.main1`

Comment: Still the same error after binding

Comment: @NamanSogani Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

Declare the refs as callbacks in each component:

```
ref={(ref) => { this.main = ref; }}
ref={(ref) => { this.main1 = ref; }}
```

Then call the component like this:

```
this.main.main1
```